# Is it possible to write in file in 20bits instead of 8,16,32 in java?

Tags: java, bit, file-writing, file-read

So I am currently working on the lzw algorithms to learn about compression and I would like to know if is it possible to write in a file with a custom size bits.

So I am using DataOutputStream and I can only write with 8, 16, and 32 bits,  but I would like to know if it is possible to write in 20 bits to save space. What I mean by saving space is when I compress my file, my code are in 19 bits and so instead of writing them in 32 with writeInt() I would like to write them using 20 bits so the compressed file will be smaller.

Comment: not 100% (only 98%) sure but its not posible with pure java. The samllest portion of data you can write to/read from input stream is byte - thus no way to store 20 bits composed of 8 bit segments. 24 is the closest one. I dont think it is even possible in native filesystem as sectors (thus data blocks) are always the power of 2

Comment: One way of doing this is compacting your data into a `long[]`, where each `long` can hold more than one piece of data. I do something similar in a [library that I've created](https://github.com/jhg023/BitBuffer/blob/master/src/main/java/bitbuffer/BitBuffer.java) for something unrelated. You might be able to adapt it to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Antoniossss how do i manage to get 24 ? i didn't see any primitive type that have 24 bits

Comment: [ImageOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#createImageOutputStream%28java.lang.Object%29) can do this.  Pass a File or OutputStream as an argument to the creation method.

Comment: @guillaume just use 3 bytes

Answer (score 1):

The smallest unit of data Java supports is a byte of 8 bits. So the smallest file you can write with Java that stores 20 bits of information is 24 bits (3 bytes) in size.

There is also the fact that the underlying file systems supported by most operating systems do not support file sizes of arbitrary bit size.

However if you mean if it's possible to have a stream of data that is semantically a sequence of 20 bit segments, sure that's possible. You just have to bitshift your data to use the methods that write 8, 16 or 32 bits.

For example 2 segments of 20 bits could be written with 5 bytes, where the first 2 bytes contain 16 bits of the first segment, the middle byte contains the remaining 4 bits of the first segment and the first 4 bits of the 2nd segment, and the last 2 bytes contain the remaining 16 bits of the 2nd segment:

```
|--------------------------------------------|
|  1st 20 bit segment  | 2nd 20 bit segment  |
|--------------------------------------------|
| byte1  | byte2  | byte3  | byte4  | byte5  |
|--------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: I don't know what bitshifting is so I may go with the 24 bits solution but how do you get 24 bits if no primitive type is 24 bits.

Comment: You use 3 bytes.